# Find all characters inbetween 2 predetermined words within a string

Tags: python-2.7, performance, findall

```
import re
big_string = "Some random //words to test@@ out //the@@ code with"
array = []
x = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('//', big_string)]
y = [n.start() for n in re.finditer('@@', big_string)] 
for i in range(len(x)):
    array.append(big_string[x[i]+2:y[i]])
print array
#output = ['words to test', 'the']
```

The above code runs fine, as you can see it finds the words between 2 strings ('//' and '@@') in a larger string. We can assume x and y will always have the same length. This code just doesn't seem very efficient, there must be a simpler or more phthonic way to achieve the same results? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer [can be seen here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%2F%5C%2F(.*%3F)%40%40&test_string=Some%20random%20%2F%2Fwords%20to%20test%40%40%20out%20%2F%2Fthe%40%40%20code%20with&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0):

```
\/\/(.*?)@@
```

We escape the `/` just in case, then capture (the `()`) everything between a `//` and `@@`, and use the non-greedy `?` so that we get every short span, not just the single long span.

The single line:

```
re.findall('//(.*?)@@', big_string)
```

Returns:

```
['words to test', 'the']
```